# Unable to retrieve Yahoo Finance stock data using pandas_datareader in Python

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-datareader

I run the following code:

```
import pandas_datareader.data as web
from datetime import date, datetime, timedelta
#
datetime_now = datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
todays_date = date.today()   # retreived in YYYY-MM-DD format
n = 7
date_n_days_ago = date.today() - timedelta(days=n)
#
mylist = ['AAPL', 'BEML.NS', 'BAJAJ-AUTO.NS', 'M&M.NS', 'JINDALSTEL.NS', 'L&TFH.NS']
#
for yahoo_symbol in mylist:
    try:
        stock_data = web.DataReader(yahoo_symbol, 'yahoo', date_n_days_ago, todays_date)
        print "success in retreiving data for: ",yahoo_symbol
    except:
        print "failed in retreiving data for: ",yahoo_symbol
```

This is the output that I receive:

```
success in retreiving data for:  AAPL
success in retreiving data for:  BEML.NS
failed in retreiving data for:  BAJAJ-AUTO.NS
failed in retreiving data for:  M&M.NS
success in retreiving data for:  JINDALSTEL.NS
failed in retreiving data for:  L&TFH.NS
```

My Doubt: Why am I unable to retrieve yahoo stock data using pandas_datareader when the symbol is "BAJAJ-AUTO.NS" or "M&M.NS", but can do the same when the symbol is " AAPL" or  "BEML.NS". Is there any work-around to retreive this data ?

PS: I have noticed that whenever the stock symbol cotains an "&" or "-" , I am unable to retreive that data from Yahoo finance using pandas_datareader

Thank you.

Comment: Perhaps you should try to HTML encode the stock names. Try querying `M%26M.NS`.

Comment: I have tried that but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
import math
import pandas_datareader as web 
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import  Dense, LSTM
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.style.use('fivethirtyeight')
```